# Setting tab cursor position in TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, tableview, keylistener

I have a javafx tableview and I'm trying to write a keylistener so the user can quickly select rows and edit their contents.

So far I can focus the table with a key press and select/focus a row with a digit key press. However I then want the user to be able to tab through the row to select the cell he wants to edit.

My problem is whenever I press the tab when a row is selected, it always starts selecting cells from the first row.

Here is the code from my key listener:

```
....
else if(code.isDigitKey()){
        TableView tv = scene.getSelectedTable();
        if(tv != null){
            tv.getSelectionModel().select(code.ordinal()-24);
            tv.getFocusModel().focus(code.ordinal()-24);
            //Something required here to set tab position to start of this row
        }else{
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to set a tab starting position?

SOLUTION:

Tab simply goes to the next JavaFX control element that it knows about. The TableView had focus so when I pressed tab it went to the next control element which just so happened to be inside the table. Tab does not traverse through table cells.

So the work around I came to was to call the edit method on the first cell in the selected row:

```
    ....
else if(code.isDigitKey()){
        TableView tv = scene.getSelectedTable();
        if(tv != null){
            tv.getSelectionModel().select(code.ordinal()-24);
            tv.getFocusModel().focus(code.ordinal()-24);
            tv.edit(code.ordinal()-24, ((TableColumn)(tv.getColumns().get(0))));
        }else{
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
```

Then in my CellFactory for that column (It happens to be a Spinner), I override startEdit:

```
@Override
public void startEdit(){
    this.spinner.requestFocus();
}
```

Note the column and table must be editable.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide an example as described there :)

Comment: In doing this I think I've seen the problem. I have various cellfactories spitting out check boxes and spinners etc, which seem to be separate entities to the table itself. So if the table or row is selected, it's still just tabbing to the next control it knows about.